# MEF - Exporting and Importing Generic types

Tags: c#, .net, inversion-of-control, mef

Due to using MEF for plugins, I'm in the process of moving away from structure IOC to just use MEF.  All has gone well .. except this scenario.

assume I have this class

```
[Export(typeof(IRepository<>))]
public class ConcreteRepository<T> : IRepository<T> {
}
```

Using structure I had a way of passing in the type so I could get a `ConcreteRepository<T>` by looking up an `IRepository<T>`

How can I achieve this using the Composition container, I though about constructing a generic method to invoke with something IRepository but would MEF resolve the export with a specific type?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can´t use a "generic type definition" for the export atribute, it has to be a specific type (may have type attributes, but they must be defined).

Can´t you just define an interface IRepositoryBase that encapsulates the methods independent of the used type parameter (if any existing)?

```
interface IRepository<T> : IRepositoryBase
```

This could then be used within the export attribute, even for derived types:

```
[Import(typeof(IRepBase))]
private IRepository<string> TestRep;
```

Comment: if that works, then great! i'll try it out.  but would have expected the imported type to match the type of the variable

Comment: Yes, it works. MEF is implictly casting the instance matching the contract to the import target property type. It causes a runtime error if the types are incompatible, of course.

Comment: so could you just export a name rather than use a type?

Comment: If would have thought so, but a simple test shows me that using a contract name instead of a type leads to a composition error. But combining it (providing a contract name AND a contract type) works, though. So, if you are unsure which type you want to provide you may explicitly define typeof(object) as the contract type.